# Unable to assign value and increment an int in C

Tags: c

I have this program to generate armstrong numbers upto a given range. But the problem is that the range variable (n in this case) is somehow acting like a const. I cannot assign a value nor increment it... There are errors during compilation with gcc. The power function works fine (Same issue with pow() defind in math.h). I would like to know why this is happening to this code and the possible fix(es). Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <math.h>

int power(int a, int b) {
    int c = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        c *= a;
    }
    return c;
}

void main(void) {
    int sum, y, temp;
    printf("temp, y, sum, n\n");
    for(int n = 1; n < 100; n++) {
        temp = n;
        printf("%d ", temp);
        y = 0; // y to hold the number of digits of n
        while (n > 0) {
            n = n / 10;
            y++;
        }
        printf("%d ", y);

        n = temp;
        sum = 0;

        while(n > 0) {
            sum += power((n % 10), y);
            n = n / 10;
        }

        if (temp == sum) {
            printf("%d ", sum);
        }

        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
temp, y, sum, n
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
.
.
.
```

Comment: `n` becomes 0 in every iteration. So in the next iteration `n++` set to 1. So it never reaches 100. You should use two different variable or reset the value of `n` at end of each iteration

Comment: Don't change your loop control variable inside the loop.  That way lies madness.

Comment: Since you can run the program to generate output, I assume you mean that there are *warnings* during compilation with gcc.  If there were errors then gcc would not produce an executable to run.

Comment: In any case, if there are warnings then the very first thing to do is to figure out what they are trying to tell you and to fix the code to resolve the warnings.  When you understand C syntax and semantics well enough to clearly articulate why it is safe to ignore a particular warning, then you can consider ignoring that warning -- otherwise, ignore warnings at your peril.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you not constantly dividing n by 10?

As n is an integer that starts as 1, and not a float, it would constantly set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `while(n > 0)` loop effectively sets `n=0` within
the outer `for` loop.
Did you want to use a second `n = temp`?

Answer (score 0):

before the last printf statement add: `n = temp;`

try you code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <math.h>

int power(int a, int b) {
    int c = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        c *= a;
    }
    return c;
}

void main(void) {
    int sum, y, temp;
    printf("temp, y, sum, n\n");
    for(int n = 1; n < 100; n++) {
        temp = n;
        printf("%d ", temp);
        y = 0; // y to hold the number of digits of n
        while (n > 0) {
            n = n / 10;
            y++;
        }
        printf("%d ", y);

        n = temp;
        sum = 0;

        while(n > 0) {
            sum += power((n % 10), y);
            n = n / 10;
        }

        if (temp == sum) {
            printf("%d ", sum);
        }
        n = temp;
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the value of n is set to 0 outside the loop. Try the below code.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
//#include <math.h>

int power(int a, int b) {
    int c = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        c *= a;
    }
    return c;
}

void main(void) {
    int sum, y, temp;
    printf("temp, y, sum, n\n");
    for(int n = 1; n < 100; n++) {
        temp = n;
        printf("%d ", temp);
        y = 0; // y to hold the number of digits of n
        while (n > 0) {
            n = n / 10;
            y++;
        }
        printf("%d ", y);

        n = temp;
        sum = 0;

        while(n > 0) {
            sum += power((n % 10), y);
            n = n / 10;
        }

        if (temp == sum) {
            printf("%d ", sum);
        }
        n = temp;
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
}
```